Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - upgrade expo sdk 52
When i run yarn expo install expo@latest i have a issue:
<--- Last few GCs --->

[23168:0000019862F52000]    51986 ms: Scavenge (interleaved) 2043.5 (2083.7) -> 2042.9 (2088.2) MB, pooled: 0 MB, 8.27 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.153, current mu = 0.146) allocation failure;
[23168:0000019862F52000]    52348 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 2046.1 (2088.2) -> 2044.8 (2083.0) MB, pooled: 0 MB, 257.83 / 0.00 ms  (+ 0.8 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 276 ms) (average mu = 0.21

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 00007FF7496DBD7B node::SetCppgcReference+16011
 2: 00007FF749644BC8 DSA_meth_get_flags+92344
 3: 00007FF74A1D2C31 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+65
 4: 00007FF74A1BFA36 v8::Function::Experimental_IsNopFunction+2918
 5: 00007FF74A00B6E0 v8::internal::StrongRootAllocatorBase::StrongRootAllocatorBase+31552
 6: 00007FF74A0053AD v8::internal::StrongRootAllocatorBase::StrongRootAllocatorBase+6157
 7: 00007FF74A000C45 v8::internal::ThreadIsolation::JitPageReference::Size+190789
 8: 00007FF74997A2DD BIO_ssl_shutdown+189
Cannot install the latest Expo package. Install expo@latest with yarn and then run npx expo install again.


I used node 20.11.0.
SDK current: 51.
Has anyone had the same problem?


Did you try to run yarn install expo@latest instead?

@wjatek i tried run yarn add expo@latest but it still same
